# Using Strucr with existing Neo4j database data

Tags: neo4j, structr

I have a Neo4j database (v3.3.4) with data in it and i'm trying to use Structr 2.3.6 with it.

I altered the Structr.config file to point to my existing Neo4j database and can see that Structr has created new Node types such as the 'AbstractNode' type of Node in the database, so I know it is communicating with the db.

I am trying to map the existing Nodes in My Database using the Structr scheme editor but when I switch to the Data tab in Structr there are no records being returned from the db? Here is what I am doing;

1. My DB contains 3000+ nodes with a type called Org which contains a
   String Title property.
2. I create a new Node type in the schema builder called Org.
3. I edit the node in the schema to Include anew LocalAttribute with a
   JSON Name of 'Title' and the DB Name of 'Title' with a type of
   string and then click the green tick.
4. I then go into Tools within the schema tab and select the Org Node
   type and click add UUIDS. (I have also tried all combinations of
   flushing cache and adding labels and re-indexing nothing works).
5. I than go into the data tab, select org and no records are returned?

What am I doing wrong please as this is very frustrating and the Structr documentation is a bit lite on how to do this, or I can't find it!

All help gratefully received as I am trying to get a POC with Neo4j through at work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the nodes "known" to Structr by adding two properties that Structr usually manages itself: "id" and "type", which must contain a random UUID (without the dashes) and the name of the type. You can set the type on your nodes using

```
MATCH (n:Org) SET n.type = "Org"
```

After that, you can use the "Add UUIDs" button in the Schema area, just go to "Schema" -> "Tools" -> Add UUIDs and select the type Org.

If you're not getting anywhere with these instructions, please let me know so I can help you.

Best,
Christian

Comment: Christian many thanks for the response. I guessed i needed to add the type and also the name property otherwise the node in Neo4j browser does not display the name. Can i suggest this info is added to your documentation if not already there?